# how to appendChild to iframe tag

Tags: javascript, iframe, appendchild

I need to append the iframeFooter to the actual iframe.  I tried the following:

```
var media = document.getElementById('media');
var foot = document.getElementById('iframeFooter');

media.appendChild(foot);

console.log(media);
```

and also:

```
$(function(){
var media = $("#media").contents().find('body');
media.append($('#iframeFooter'));
```

```js
$(function(){
var media = $("#media").contents().find('body');
media.append($('#iframeFooter'));

    
    
    
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id='media' src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1EhOE6w1_iHeWWpE_Y52YQjVKf3jxXOV6" ></iframe>
<div id="iframeFooter"><span style="background-color:grey">click pin for details of gas leak</span></div>
```

Comment: If the iframe is in another domain, you can not touch it

Comment: ahh, foiled again